# Where does one use holomorphicity in the proof of Goursat's theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

Goursat's theorem: Let $f : U \to \mathbb{C}$ be a function that is holomorphic on the open set $U$. If $T$ is a triangle in $U$ and $\gamma$ is some smooth parametrization of that triangle, then $\int_{\gamma} f = 0$.

My question: Is this no longer true if I replace holomorphic with differentiable?

The proof I am reading proceeds by dividing $T$ into quarter triangles, and arguing that the integral over $T$ must be bounded above by 4 times the integral of one of the quarter triangles. The argument proceeds by induction to show that this bound forces the integral over $T$ to vanish.

There seems to be only one place where the assumption that $f$ is holomorphic is used - namely, we use it to write $f(z) = f(z_0) + f'(z_0)h + h \phi(h)$, with $h = (z - z_0)$ $\phi(h)$ converging to zero as $h \to 0$. Let $T^n$ be the $nth$ triangle chosen in the typical method of proof. $p^n$ denotes its perimeter, and $d^n$ the diameter.

Supposing that $f$ was merely $R^2$ differentiable, I can create a similar expression: $f(z) = f(z_0) + f'(z_0)(h) + |h| \phi(h)$, and conclude that $\int_{T^n} f(z) =  \int_{T^n} (f(z_0) + f'(z_0)(h)) + \int_{T^n} (|h| \phi(h))$.

I want to claim that  $(f(z_0) + f'(z_0)(h))$ has a primitive since it is the sum of a constant function and a linear function (however, I think that the constant part has no primitive, since it is a vector and not scalar, so it is not the derivitive of $"f(z_0) x"$ - this is wrong, see below), so that we are left with $\int_{T^n} f(z) = \int_{T^n} (|h| \phi(h)) \leq \sup (|h| \phi(h)) p^{(n)}$ ($p^n$ is the perimeter of $T^n$).

Since $\sup |h| \phi(h) \leq d^n \sup \phi(h)$, it seems like the same exact proof goes through as in the holomorphic case.

Can someone help me find my mistake?

Comment: I wonder, is the primitive really a primitive as you claim? Would be nice to see more detail there.

Comment: Hmm, my comment regarding typos didn't get entered. The most serious notational issue is the $f'(h)$. The proof I address below.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook I think the constant part has no primitive, since the function $f'(z_0) x$ is not in general defined as $f'(z_0)$ is a vector and not a scalar, and $x$ takes vector values. I'm not sure how to prove that it has no primitive, but at least my naive assumption is wrong.

Comment: No problem with constants. It's the linear part that's the issue. See my computation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have a statement you know is incorrect, but you think you have a proof, it is always a good idea to see what happens when you apply your proof to an explicit counterexample.  In this way, you should be able to find the mistake or misconception.

In this case, one of the easiest counterexamples is $f(z) = \overline{z}$ (the complex conjugate).  Take the triangle to be the real axis from $0$ to $1$, the diagonal line from $1$ to $i$, and then the imaginary axis from $i$ to $0$.  The integral should have value equal to $i$ (if I haven't miscalculated), rather than $0$.  Now try to see where your argument goes wrong!

---

Added:  for this kind of question, it is helpful to think of the domain copy of $\mathbb C$ as being $\mathbb R^2$ (so depending on two parameters), but the
target copy of $\mathbb C$ as just being $\mathbb C$, a field of scalars.

In other words, we think of complex valued functions of two real variables.

Now we usually work in terms of $\partial_x$ and $\partial_y$ when studying functions on $\mathbb R^2$, but when the functions are complex valued, we can instead work in terms of $\partial_z :=  \dfrac{1}{2}(\partial_x - i \partial_y)$ 
and $\partial_{\overline{z}} := \dfrac{1}{2}(\partial_x + i \partial_y).$

If $F$ is any (sufficiently differentiable) function, and $\gamma$ is a path between two complex numbers $a$ and $b$, we then find that 
$$\int_{\gamma} \partial_z F(z) d z + \int_{\gamma} \partial_{\overline{z}} F(z)  d\overline{z} = F(b) - F(a).$$
You can check this for yourself; it is just a rewriting of the (probably) more
familiar formula  $$ \int_{\gamma} \partial_x F(z) dx + \int_{\gamma} \partial_y
F(z) dy = F(b) - F(a).$$

When you are looking for a "primitive" to compute a line integral $\int_{\gamma} f(z) dz,$ then, what you are trying to do is to write $f(z)$ as $\partial_z F(z)$
for some $F(z)$ which satisfies $\partial_{\overline{z}} F = 0$ identically, 
and then apply the above formula.

This isn't always possible, anymore then it is possible to always write a function
of two variables as $\partial_x$ of some function whose $\partial_y$ vanishes.

Indeed, the Cauchy--Riemann equations can be expressed as saying that
$\partial_{\overline{z}} F = 0$ at every point.    You can further check
that, for a holomorphic functions, $\partial_z$ is just the usual complex derivative.

So if you can find a "primitive" $F$for $f$ as above, then $F$ is holomorphic, and hence so is $f$ (being the derivative of a holomorphic function).  So you can find a primitive, and hence get integral zero, precisely in the holomorphic case.

---

The discussion is perhaps easier when expressed in terms of differential forms,
if you know that language.  Then we have the formula, for smooth functions on $\mathbb R^2$:
$$\int_{\gamma} dF  =  F(b) - F(a)$$
(the one-dimensional form of Stokes's theorem, which I guess classically is just the fundamental theorem of calculus), 
and we can write $dF$ either as $\partial_x F dx + \partial_y F dy,$
or instead as $\partial_z F dz + \partial_{\overline{z}}F d\overline{z}$.
(It is just a question of choosing $dz$ and $d\overline{z}$ as a basis
for the complexified one-forms, rather than $dx$ and $dy$.)

We also have the formula, for a closed curve $\gamma$ bounding a region $\Delta$,
that
$$\int_{\gamma} f dz = \int_{\Delta} d(f dz) = \int_{\Delta} \partial_{\overline{z}}
f d\overline{z} \wedge dz$$
(the two-dimensional form of Stokes's theorem, I guess classically known as
Green's theorem in the plane).
Now one computes $d \overline{z} \wedge dz = 2i dx \wedge dy,$
so we find that
$$\int_{\gamma} f dz = 2i \int_{\Delta} \partial_{\overline{z}} f dx \wedge dy,$$
where $dx \wedge dy$ is the usual area form.

If $f$ is holomorphic, then $\partial_{\overline{z}} f = 0,$ and so
this integral vanishes.  But if e.g. $f = \overline{z}$, then this
partial derivative equals $1$, so we are just computing $2i$ times the
area of $\Delta$.  (This is one way to get the answer of $i$ for the
line integral around a triangle I described above.)

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to write this out. This is very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

We can write $f(z) = f(z_0) + f'(z_0)h + h \phi(h)$, with $h = (z - z_0)$ and  $\phi(h) \to 0$ as $h \to 0$ *exactly* when $f$ is holomorphic (that is, complex differentiable).

When $f$ is just $\mathbb R^2$ differentiable you get $f(z) = f(z_0) + \nabla f(z_0) \cdot (h_x,h_y) + \cdots$, which is not the same thing.

Comment: When $f$ is $R^2$ differentiable you can write $f(z) = f(z_0) + f'(h) + |h| \phi(h)$, with $\phi(h) \to 0$ as $|h| \to 0$. This is almost the same thing (h is replaced by $|h|$, since vector addition is not defined), and I don't think that it affects the estimation of the integral. So I don't think that this is were the issue is.

Comment: Again, there are notational issues here. But, yes, the definition of differentiability for a map $\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2$ is that $f(z) = f(z_0) + Df(z_0)(z-z_0) + \varepsilon (z)$, where $\varepsilon(z)/|z-z_0|\to 0$ as $z\to z_0$.

Comment: @TedShifrin: Dear Ted, If you were going to write a smooth function in terms of complex coordinates, I would have expected to see a $\overline{z}$-term appearing in the linear approximation as well, so I think I'm a bit confused by your comment.  Best wishes,

Comment: @user54092: Dear user, Your description of differentiability is not correct.  You are looking at a function from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb C$, and so the linear term will involve both the $x$ and $y$-coord. of $h$ (as lhf indicates).  Regards,

Comment: @Matt: I admit I was being lazy and writing $z$ for $(x,y)$. These are all vectors and $Df(z_0)$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix.

Comment: @TedShifrin: Dear Ted, Ah, so you were agreeing with lhf.  So everyone is on the same page except perhaps the OP!  Cheers,

Comment: @MattE I had been meaning to write $f'(z_0) h$, with $h$ a vector and $f'(z_0): R^2 \to R^2$ a linear function. What I wrote above and in my post is definitely not correct, but the error in my reasoning seems to be in my assumption that constant functions have a primitive, not in my terrible abuse of notation. (At least, that is one error in my reasoning.)

Comment: @user54092: Dear user, Constant functions are certainly holomorphic, and so their integral around a triangle will vanish.  I'm not sure how this reconciles with your statement about constant functions not having a primitive.  If you want to think in terms of primitives, then it seems best to think in terms of the operators $\partial_z$ and $\partial_{\overline{z}}$.  You want to try to write your linear function as a derivative with respect to $z$ alone, ignoring the $\overline{z}$-variable. This is fine for the constant (it is the derivative w.r.t. $z$ of the same constant times $z$), but ...

Comment: ... is typically not okay for the linear function.  E.g. the linear function $z$ is the derivative w.r.t. $z$ of $z^2/2$, but the linear function $\overline{z}$ is not a derivative w.r.t. $z$ of anything; rather it is the derivative w.r.t. $\overline{z}$ of $\overline{z}^2/2$.  So the problem is in the linear term, not the constant term, as far as I can tell.  Regards,

Comment: @MattE Okay - right. Constant functions are certainly holomorphic, and therefore have primitives, and I can make $f(z_0) x$ meaningful by identifying $R^2$ with $C$. Could you explain what it means to think in terms of the operators $\partial_z$ and $\partial_{\overline z}$? (Or point me to a reference.)

Comment: @user54092: Dear user, Rather than continue this in comments, I added something to my answer.  Regards,

Answer (score 3):

Remember that $f=u+iv$ is a $\Bbb C$-valued function and we are considering the line integral
$$\int_\gamma f(z)\,dz = \int_\gamma (u+iv)(dx+i\,dy)= \int_\gamma (u\,dx - v\,dy)+i(v\,dx+u\,dy).$$
When you get down to the linear approximation of a differentiable function $(u,v)\colon\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2$, you will have something resembling
$$\int_\gamma \big((Ax + By) + i(Cx+Dy)\big)\, dx + i\big((Ax + By) + i(Cx+Dy)\big)\, dy\,,$$
which won't have a primitive (and hence won't have integral $0$) unless $B+iD=iA-C$. This looks a lot like the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

**ADDED**: Where did $B+iD=iA-C$ come from?  $\displaystyle\int_\gamma ax\,dx + by\,dy = 0$ for all $a,b$ and closed curves $\gamma$. This follows from Green's Theorem or from noticing that $F(x,y)=\frac12(ax^2+by^2)$ is a primitive. But what about $\displaystyle\int_\gamma ay\,dx + bx\,dy$? Again, Green's Theorem tells us that when $\gamma$ bounds a region $R$, this integral is $\displaystyle\iint_R (b-a)\,dxdy$. Thus, if we want this integral to be $0$ for all such $\gamma$, we need $a=b$. Alternatively, we can see that $a=b$ is necessary and sufficient for us to have a (smooth) function $F$ with $\displaystyle\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} = ay$ and $\displaystyle\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} = by$, inasmuch as $b=\displaystyle\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x\partial y} = \displaystyle\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial y\partial x}=a$.

Comment: I see why there is an answer here, but I am absolutely confused about how to evaluate that second line integral in order to get the result $B + iD = iA - C$. I'm not sure what to do with $\int_{\gamma} x dx$ or $\int_{\gamma} y dx$... I'm not sure how to interpret these integrals, really. Is the first a path integral on x axis with values just the x coordinate of $\gamma$? That would give \int_0^1 x(\gamma(t)) \gamma'(t) dt = \int d/dt (x(\gamma(t)) dt = x\gamma(1) - x\gamma(0) = 0... the other would be the same, giving a (useless) total of 0. So I'm certainly misinterpreting something...

Comment: (Thank you for your help, by the way.)

Comment: I've edited, but it does sound like you need to learn something about line integrals and Green's Theorem. :) And, no, $\int_\gamma y\,dx$ is never $0$ for a closed curve $\gamma$, unless the curve is just a point.

Comment: I really do - is there a resource you can recommend? I know enough to make sense of your manipulations, at least formally, so I can see how you arrive at that equation.

Comment: A standard multivariable calculus book should do. If you want more rigor, my profile has a link to my course from this spring with YouTube videos (this includes integration, line integrals, Green's Theorem, etc. — the first half of the course should get videoed this fall).

Comment: I am definitely looking for more rigor - equations that I don't completely understand never stick in my memory for longer than I need them to pass an exam...