# Goursat's Theorem and Real Differentiability

Tags: complex-analysis

I've been studying Stein and Shakarchi's proof of Goursat's theorem in complex analysis, which states

> If $\Omega$ is an open set in $\mathbb{C}$ and $T \subset \Omega$ is a triangle whose interior is also contained in $\Omega$ then
>   \begin{equation*}
> \int_{T} f(z) \ \mathrm{d} z = 0
> \end{equation*}
>   whenever $f$ is holomorphic in $\Omega$.

In the proof, which I could post if needed, the only thing they seem to require which is a consequence of holomorphy is the existence of a 'good' linear approximation in the neighborhood of every point $z \in \Omega$, i.e.
\begin{equation*}
f(w) = f(z) + f'(z)(w-z) + o(|w-z|)
\end{equation*}
But this condition is exactly met by real-differentiable functions, so does the theorem hold for real-differentiable functions in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$?

Comment: Observe!!! That here $f'$ is a $\mathbb{C}$ linear map...

Comment: as the comment above might lead you... note that the difference between real and complex differentiability in the plane is the fact that the complex case allows the differential to be written as a multiplication of a complex number. In contrast, real differentiable allows many other possibilities, you need two complex numbers and the product of $w-z$ as well as the conjugate to capture real differentiability... sorry if this comment is cryptic, I'll try to find something to link.

Comment: you should read http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/833471/where-does-one-use-holomorphicity-in-the-proof-of-goursats-theorem?rq=1